# Cavalieri's principle and integrals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $f$ be a continuous function an $[a,b]$. Let $P\subset R^2$ be the figure under the graph of $f$ and $D \subset R^3$ a solid figure obtained by rotating a plane curve around $x$-axis. Using **Cavalieri's principle** show that ($\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure):
$$\nu_2(P)=\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$$

and
$$\nu_3(D)=\pi\int_a^b(f(x))^2 \, dx$$

I get the first formula by doing the Riemann sums, but I don't think I use the Cavalieri's principle there... I write $\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \, \Delta x_i$ and than I want to go to infinity: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \, \Delta x_i=\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

In the second example I can see that I've got "a sum" of disks of radius $f(x)$.

But in both examples I don't know how I shoudl formally use the **Cavalieri's principle**. Any ideas?